# Everytime I click a button the first row is always changed

Tags: jquery, css

This worked fine but whenever I click the two remove buttons the first button of view is always changed. My aim is to change the view button's width which corresponds with the remove buttons ID.

**PHP**:

```
<?php 
  foreach($studentDetails as $studentDetailsSHOW) {

     <button class="view" value="<?php echo $studentDetailsShow['id']?>">
     Add</button> //View values are 1 and 2

     <button class="remove" value="<?php echo studentDetailsSHOW['id']" > ✕ </button> 
     //Remove values are 1 and 2

   }
}?>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
   $(".remove").click(function() {
      $view_btn = $(".view_btn_click").attr('value');

      if($view_btn.val() == $(this).val()){
         $view_btn.css({width:"20px"});
      }

   }
</script>
```

Comment: You are using a class ***.view_btn_click*** on javascript but adding class ***view*** in php, should those be the same? Also do the students have any parent element (ie. div etc) that you could simply use (.parent().find(".view")) to look for the view button alot easier. Can you add the rendered html example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(".remove").click(function() {
    var _self = $(this);
    $(".view").each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == _self.val()){
         $(this).css('width', '20px');
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing the correct view element to make the css/width change.

try this

```
<script>
   $(".remove").click(function() {
      var id = $(this).val();
      $('.view_btn_click[value="'+ id +'"]').css({width:"20px"});
   }
</script>
```